# Modify a function to pass an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a Javascript html game from a template we were given as part of an assignment. I'm totally new to Javascript but have managed to get all my game elements in except my missile. I want to change the missile from the code below (as it uses colored rectangles) rather than an actual image so that my player can fire missiles from the png. There is an array for the missiles but the function itself is using rgb colours. How do I pass an image to the function?

Also I do have an external display object attached to the game file. Any suggestions would be nice, because I'm stuck.

Missile function:

```
function Missile ( x,y, width, height, dx, dy) { //dx and dy is the direction the bullet will fire.

    //no image because we will overright the draw method to use canvas drawing.
    DisplayObject.call(this,'missile', undefined, x,y, width, height);

    //declare private variables

    var alive = true;

    var facingX = dx;
    var facingY = dy;

    var hue = 0;
    var sat = 1.0;
    var lightness = 0.5;

    // public functions

    this.update = function () {
        //move missile
        hue+=0.06;
        if(hue>1) hue=0;
        this.x += facingX*15;
        this.y += facingY*15;
    }

    this.draw = function (context) {

        for(var i = 0; i<4; i++) {

            var h = hue-(i*0.06);
            if(h<0) h+=1.0;
            var rgb = hslToRgb(h,sat,lightness);
            context.fillStyle = "rgb("+Math.round(rgb[0])+","+Math.round(rgb[1])+","+Math.round(rgb[2])+")";
            context.fillRect(this.x-(facingX*i*5),this.y-(facingY*i*5),5,5);
        }
    }

    this.kill = function () {
        alive = false;
    }

    this.isDead = function () {
        return !alive;
    }
}

Missile.prototype = new DisplayObject();

function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

display object:

```
Image.prototype.draw = function draw (context,x,y, w,h) {
    if(context) context.drawImage(this,x,y,w || this.width, h || this.height);
};

//define rectangle object that DisplayObject will inherit from.
var Rect2d = function (x,y,width,height) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.width = width || 1;
    this.height = height || 1;
};

var DisplayObject = function (name, image, x,y, width, height) {
    if(image) Rect2d.call(this,x,y,width || image.width, height || image.height);
    else Rect2d.call(this,x,y,width,height);
    this.name = name || '';
    this.img = image;
    this.alpha = 1.0;
};

DisplayObject.prototype = new Rect2d(); 
//if you do not use new here then anything you add to DisplayObject.prototype is added to Rect2d            

//add functions to Display object. Because these are added to the prototype 
//they are not visible if you use the hasOwnProperty method on a DisplayObject.
DisplayObject.prototype.setImage = function (img) {
    this.img = img;
    return this;
};

DisplayObject.prototype.scaleToImage = function () {
    if(this.img) {
        this.width = this.img.width;
        this.height = this.img.height;
    }
    return this;
};

//this function wraps our new Image draw() method
DisplayObject.prototype.draw = function (context) {
    //var tmp_alpha = context.globalAlpha;
    //context.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    this.img.draw(context, this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
    //context.globalAlpha = tmp_alpha;
    return this;
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the DisplayObject class?

Comment: @AlexMA Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how DisplayObject is defined, it could be simple as adding a parameter:

```
function Missile ( x,y, width, height, dx, dy, image) {     
    DisplayObject.call(this,'missile', image, x,y, width, height);

    ...
}
```

And then you would simply remove the overwritten `draw` method.

If you post the code for DisplayObject, I might be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: thanks thats really helpful!! i'll try that and see how i got i will post up the DisplayObject :)

Comment: this code will still work, the only thing to note is that you'll want to pass in an Image object and not just the url of the image.

Comment: i understand i pass an image to the function but im just not sure how i do it. Everytime i get rid of the original drawn missile my game stops working and freezes when it starts.

Comment: Thanks sp much for your help once more!